# Listing users with access to NetFrameworkConfigurationKey ACL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, encryption

I have added some users to the Access Control List(ACL) for the **RSA** Key Container using  “**aspnet_regiis** -pa "**NetFrameworkConfigurationKey**" "USER" . How can I list out all the users who have been given access to the NetFrameworkConfigurationKey?

Can it be through aspnet_regiis command?

Comment: This seems kind of dangerous. If I know who has access to it, then I know which PC to sit by until they go to lunch (without locking their PC).

Comment: But how do I verify that atleast a particular user has access? Any alternative you can think of?

Comment: Try and see? The most secure methods of user authentication provide the absolute least amount of information about which users have access to them. *1st Rule: You do not talk about Fight Club* _2nd Rule: You **DO NOT** talk about fight club_. In this circumstance, of course, the program is *part* of fight club.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done (I have no idea actually), but if it can... then I'd see that as a security problem.

Comment: Again, I don't know (and no one else seems to be chipping in) so *try it* and see what happens. Worst case scenario: It gives an error saying the user already exists. Best case: it doesn't care, ignores it and moves on. Those could be reversed depending on your goals, but either way you should just try it and see what happens. MS is pretty good about protecting you from shooting yourself in the foot without first warning you about it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Find the file that contains the key. If this is a machine key, they are located here: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

   - You can open these files as text; look for `NetFrameworkConfigurationKey` on the first line.
   - On machines I have tested with, the correct file seems to start with `d6d9`
2. Just right-click on the file, Properties, and view the Security tab

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt technique:

1. Find the hex value (69 characters long) of your named key.

`certutil -key NetFrameworkConfigurationKey`

2. Use `icacls` to list users and permissions.

`icacls %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\<your hex value>`

Where permissions are represented by:
N = no access
F = full access
M = modify access
RX = read and execute access
R = read-only access
W = write-only access
D = delete access