# Are there any restrictions when encrypting elements in web config?

Tags: c#, iis, encryption, web-config, rsa

I find that using

```
  "aspnet_regiis" -pef
```

or

```
  "aspnet_regiis -pe"
```

to encrypt elements in web.cong works only on several elements and not the others.

i.e. it works for "ConnectionStrings" and "appSettings" but not for "system.web"

Can I encrypt all the elements somehow? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt more that the connectionStrings? Is it not the purpose of the .config file to be easy configurable?

Comment: Yes. But I have nlog configuration section in web.config which include database connection string. I cant leave it plain in the file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe system.web/identity -app /[vdir]
```

identity being a section within system.web

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to encrypt additional sections such as nlog connection string section, but with no success. Is there a list of allowed/restricted elements to encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

After googling for a long time I have found the solution.

Putting it here for future reference of other users.

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504883/encrypting-custom-sections-of-a-web-config) has a solution by Adam - he called it a terrible hack and I agree but it works.

All i did was copy nlog.dll to the .NET framework library and the problem was solved when I ran the command.

Explanation - 
the  element point to the intefrace NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler in nlog.dll as follows:

```
  <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
```

For god knows why, when the element is encrypted - the aspnet_regiis searches for this dll and when it doesnt find it - it fails.
Just copy it to c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vXXXX